# why do I dismount my mount when I attack

Tags: terraria

I have gotten the UFO and the drill containment mount and when I attack it despawns and this is on any mount can someone tell me why this is happening

Answer (score 3):

It despawns because you cannot use tools or weapons while in the DCU.

> Unlike other mounts, players cannot use any tools or weapons while riding the Drill Mount.

[source](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Drill_Containment_Unit)

Comment: The DCU doesn't despawn when you attack in it, it just fails to attack. This also doesn't explain why the UFO is despawning.